# HTML code-duplication (link button) when Google Translate is active

Tags: html, google-translate, code-duplication

please, if you can see this: http://www.agenzia-italia.it , in the top-right corner you can see the Google Translate menu.

If you choose "English" and scrolling down the page, you can see that in the real estate listings the link "Property details >" is repeated twice. 
Screenshot:

[image]

Can you help me please?

Thanks,
bye bye and New year Greetings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://translate.google.com/support/?hl=en

General information for webmasters Preventing translation of your webpages

If you don't mind your web page being translated by Google Translate, except for a particular section (like an email address, for example), just add class=notranslate to any HTML element to prevent that element from being translated. For example: Email us at sales at example dot com

Comment: Hi Oli,thanks for your answer. 
But i want to translate the anchor text of the link. "Property details" it's right... i don't want it to appear twice. 
Or, excuse me, I don't understand well your answer...

Thanks,
bye bye!

Comment: Hi,
i have added <span class="notranslate"> to the link and now the button isn't repeat but the anchor-text is in italian.

Google Translate can give me some PHP post variable? Something like lang=en , so i could translate the anchor-text manually with IF control...

Thanks, bye!